# Is Bitcoin network an overlay application network?

Tags: network

Is Bitcoin network constructed with just Layers 1-4 of the OSI model? Or it's an overlay application network?

Can someone please explain about structure of Bitcoin network?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It sits in the application layer as there's the Bitcoin P2P protocol that runs on of TCP. The P2P protocol has to be implemented for nodes to communicate with each other (i.e. block, tx, inv messages).

Comment: Thank you, so why it is not possible to use some specific network configurations such as ex. Cisco Port Security to do some specific jobs such as recognizing MAC address change using Cisco Port Security? The main question is asked here (https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/54596/36813), where some people believe that it is not possible to use some configurations such as Cisco Port Security in a blockchain network? Thanks

Comment: I believe your other question has the appropriate answers to ^ https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/80883/possibility-of-detecting-mac-address-change-on-bitcoin-network